# Jenkins Pipeline on different environment

Tags: jenkins

We have two environments:
1. Jenkins running on windows (master)
2. Jenkins running on Mac (slave)

Step 1: Create a job that triggers .Net exe and result of this job is a folder containing list of files like xml and images
Step 2: Once this folder is generated, transfer this folder to slave Job workspace
steps 3: trigger android job.

Require 1: Need pipeline code that executes master job first and next slave job
Require 2: Pipeline code that copies folder from master to salve and trigger job on slave.

I am not finding much help any where. Please help me on this pipeline code.
Thanks in Advance

Thanks,
Raj4MS

Comment: node('Master') {
  stage('stage 1') {

    echo 'stash stage 1'
    stash includes: "Build/**/*", name: "build-stuff"
  }
}
node('DRB.WLMA.JENKIN.SLAVE') {
  stage('stage 2') {
     echo 'unstash stage 2'
     unstash "build-stuff"
  }
}